# error when installing smartsheet-python-sdk on mac

Tags: python, macos, smartsheet-api

I'm getting the following error when installing the smartsheet-python-sdk package on my Mac. Can anyone give me any pointers?

```
> dleclair-mbp:smartsheet dleclair$ sudo pip install
> smartsheet-python-sdk   
>.
>.  
> smartsheet-python-sdk) Collecting six>=1.9 (from
> smartsheet-python-sdk)   Downloading six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
>     os.chflags(dst, st.st_flags) OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted:
> '/tmp/pip-yDYmT1-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six-1.4.1-py2.7.egg-info'
> dleclair-mbp:smartsheet dleclair$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this post that refers to a known issue with python package dependencies on OS X 10.11 and to work around it using the '--ignore-installed' flag on the pip command and it worked!

[link to solution post](https://github.com/donnemartin/haxor-news/issues/54)

```
Installing collected packages: requests, six, certifi, python-dateutil, requests-toolbelt, smartsheet-python-sdk
Successfully installed certifi-2017.4.17 python-dateutil-2.6.0 requests-2.14.2 requests-toolbelt-0.8.0 six-1.10.0 smartsheet-python-sdk-1.2.0
```